# Ensure specific std::array position at compile time

Tags: c++, c++17, std

I have an `std::array` with entries I want at a specific position according to the `index` of my `Variable` class at compile time:

```
#include <string_view>
#include <array>

struct Variable
{
  size_t index;
  std::string_view name;
}

constexpr std::array<Variable, 3> myarray {{{0, "myvar1"},
                                            {1, "myvar2"},
                                            {2, "myvar3"}}};
```

Now I can ensure the position at compile time with a static assert:

```
static_assert(myarray[0].index == 0);
static_assert(myarray[1].index == 1);
static_assert(myarray[2].index == 2);
```

This avoids typing errors as:

```
constexpr std::array<Variable, 3> myarray {{{0, "myvar1"},
                                            {2, "myvar2"}, // wrong index for array position 1
                                            {2, "myvar3"}}};
```

But this is error prone and violates the principle of "single source of truth". What I want is for example the reverse of `std::get<T>`:

```
constexpr std::size_t index0 = 0;
std::set<index0>(myarray, {index0, "singen"});
```

But this does not exist, how would I achieve this in C++17?

Comment: The initializer for `std::array`, as for plain arrays, will initialize the array in the order of the elements in the initializer list. That's guaranteed.

Comment: what do you mean with "ensure the position" ? If you initialize a const array with those three elements, there is no way they can change their position (dirty hacks aside)

Comment: on the other hand there is no need to store the index inside the elements. `it - myarray.begin()` will always give you the correct index from an iterator to an element

Comment: Or perhaps you want [*designated initializers*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Designated_initializers)? Those are coming in C++20, but if you're lucky your compiler already have some C++20 compatibility, or implement it as extension to older versions.

Comment: I clarified the question. As I want to pass the `myarray[n]` to other classes without the `myarray` I need to know the index.

Comment: As for avoiding typos like the ones you seem to be worried about, that's for *unit testing* to find. *Or* don't have an `index` member at all, and just use the array index?

Comment: so the potential mistake you are worried about is a typo on the array initialization that causes element at index `i` to have a `index` different from `i` ?

Comment: @idclev463035818 yes exactly

Comment: then i would rather try to automate the initialization of the array such that you do not have to explicitly mention the indicees. Don't know how to do that, and don't have time atm :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might use `std::get` for your hypothetical `std::set<index0>(myarray, {index0, "singen"})`:

```
constexpr std::size_t index0 = 0;
std::get<index0>(myarray) = {index0, "singen"};
```

But seems simpler to rework your array creation:

```
constexpr std::array<Variable, 3> make_myarray()
{
    std::array<Variable, 3> res{};
    std::array<std::string_view, 3> strings = {"myvar1", "myvar2", "myvar3"};

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != res.size(); ++i) {
        res[i] = {i, strings[i]};
    }
    return res;
}
```

And then

```
constexpr std::array<Variable, 3> myarray = make_myarray();
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5468b5b6ee93aff8)

You might even create lambda instead of regular function and call it directly:

```
constexpr std::array<Variable, 3> myarray = [](){
    std::array<Variable, 3> res{};
    std::array<std::string_view, 3> strings = {"myvar1", "myvar2", "myvar3"};

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != res.size(); ++i) {
        res[i] = {i, strings[i]};
    }
    return res;
}();
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bbcace62d1f6014d)

or even create your check function

```
template <std::size_t N>
constexpr bool is_valid(const std::array<Variable, N>& a) {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != a.size(); ++i) {
        if (a[i].index != i) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

constexpr std::array<Variable, 3> myarray {{{0, "myvar1"},
                                            {2, "myvar2"}, // wrong index for array position 1
                                            {2, "myvar3"}}};

static_assert(is_valid(myarray)); // Trigger here.
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/84da91048d9aaebd)

Comment: I added alternative solutions to your needs.

Comment: I can't compile any of your possible methods?

Comment: @Reza: Added demo link (only last one had typo)

Comment: Thanks! Why can't I use a `std::tuple` in your second example with the lambda call? (as in `std::array<std::tuple<float, float>, 3> bounds = {{10,2},{1,3},{3,4}};`

Comment: You might do `std::array<std::tuple<float, float>, 3> bounds{{{10,2},{1,3},{3,4}}};`. `array` uses aggregate initialization with some braces which can be omitted in some context.

Comment: My problems lays with the assignment `res[i] = {i, strings[i], bounds[i]};` where I get errors when `bounds` is of type `std::tuple`

Comment: I suggest to ask new question.

Comment: Here is my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60071381/why-cant-i-use-a-stdtuple-in-a-constexpr-lamda-function