# Why can't I use a std::tuple in a constexpr lambda function

Tags: c++, c++17, stdtuple

I have the following code:

```
#include <string_view>
#include <array>
#include <tuple>

struct Variable
{
  size_t index;
  std::string_view name;
  std::tuple<float, float> bounds;
};

constexpr std::array<Variable, 3> myarray = [](){
    std::array<Variable, 3> res{};
    std::array<std::string_view, 3> strings = {"myvar1", "myvar2", "myvar3"};
    std::array<std::tuple<float, float>, 3> bounds = {{{0,1}, {1,2}, {2,3}}};

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != res.size(); ++i) {
        res[i] = {i, strings[i], bounds[i]};
    }
    return res;
}();
```

but this code does not compile due to the `std::tuple`. What is the reason I can't use `std::tuple` inside a lambda function?

I'm using

```
c++ -Wall -Winvalid-pch -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=c++17 -g -o main.o -c main.cpp
```

to compile the code.

Version of the compiler is: `gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)`

The error I get is:

```
../main.cpp:53:3: error: call to non-constexpr function ‘<lambda()>’
 }();
   ^
../main.cpp:44:51: note: ‘<lambda()>’ is not usable as a constexpr function because:
 constexpr std::array<Variable, num_vars> xrt = [](){
                                               ^
../main.cpp:51:39: error: call to non-constexpr function ‘Variable& Variable::operator=(Variable&&)’
     res[i] = {i, strings[i], bounds[i]};
                                   ^
../main.cpp:16:8: note: ‘Variable& Variable::operator=(Variable&&)’ is not usable as a constexpr function because:
 struct Variable
        ^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: What compiler are you using? What version of it? What flags or options do you give the compiler when building? What errors do you get? And why do you think it's the `std::tuple` that's the problem? Lastly, when creating a [mcve] please try to make sure it doesn't contain any other unrelated errors (like missing semicolons).

Comment: According to clang, problem lies here: `res[i] = {i, strings[i], bounds[i]};`

Comment: you forgot ; after Variable declaration. Also be sure to include `<string>`, `<string_view>` might just forward-declare it.

Comment: tuple assignment operators aren't constexpr until c++20: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator%3D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither `tuple` nor `pair` have constexpr assignment in C++17.

But even a trivial struct containing pair of values would do the job. You may want to implement own constexpr-compatible structure if required. Trivial version without fluff you need:

```
struct Couple {
  float a, b;  
};

struct Variable
{
  size_t index;
  std::string_view name;
  Couple bounds;
};

constexpr std::array<Variable, 3> myarray = [](){
    std::array<Variable, 3> res{};
    std::array<std::string_view, 3> strings = {"myvar1", "myvar2", "myvar3"};
    std::array<Couple, 3> bounds = {{{0,1}, {1,2}, {2,3}}};

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != res.size(); ++i) {
        res[i] = {i, strings[i], bounds[i]};
    }
    return res;
}();
```

It's possible to arrangle code the way it would use `tuple` for future standard

Comment: could you clarify your last sentence?

Comment: @Reza  something like `#if __cplusplus > 201703L  \  template <class ...Args> using Couple = std::tuple<Args...>; \ # else  \ /*Your definition of Couple */ `

Answer (score 1):

`std::tuple`'s [assignment operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator%3D) are not `constexpr` until c++20. If you avoid assignment operators and construct your tuples in-place then your code compiles:

```
constexpr std::array<Variable, 3> myarray = [](){
    std::array<std::string_view, 3> strings = {"myvar1", "myvar2", "myvar3"};
    std::array<std::tuple<float, float>, 3> bounds = {{{0,1}, {1,2}, {2,3}}};

    std::array<Variable, 3> res { {
        {0, strings[0], bounds[0]},
        {1, strings[1], bounds[1]},
        {2, strings[2], bounds[2]}
    } };
    return res;
}();
```

Comment: Idea of the initial loop was to enforce that `res[i].index == i`.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, but with just 3 elements its pretty easy to see it is correct

Comment: Whole lambda is then unneeded for 3 elements ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Since C++14, `std::tuple`'s constructors are `constexpr` (at least the ones not accepting allocators), so you could use one of those instead of the assignment operator.

Start adding a `constexpr` constructor to your class

```
struct Variable
{
    size_t index{};
    std::string_view name{};
    std::tuple<float, float> bounds{};

    constexpr Variable(size_t i, std::string_view str)
        : index{i}, name{str}, bounds{i, i + 1} {}
};
```

Then, you could construct the array using a couple of template functions taking advantage of [std::integer_sequence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence).

```
template <class Element, std::size_t... I, typename... ArgsType>
constexpr auto make_array_with_indices_impl(std::index_sequence<I...>, ArgsType... args)
{
    return std::array<Element, sizeof...(args)>{
        Element(I, args)...
    };    
}

template <class Element, typename... ArgsType>
constexpr auto make_array_with_indices(ArgsType... args)
{
    return make_array_with_indices_impl<Element>(
        std::index_sequence_for<ArgsType...>{}, args...
    );
}
```

[Here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/OBWMTIXkXg5yyjvN) an example of their usage.